# Difference between indicator column and categorical identity column in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am learning Tensorflow and came across different [feature columns](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/feature_columns) used in Tensorflow . Out of these types, two are [`categorical_identity_column`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/feature_columns#categorical_identity_column) and [`indicator_column`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/feature_columns#indicator_and_embedding_columns). Both have been defined in the same way. As far as I understand, both convert categorical column to one-hot encoded column.

So my question is what is the difference between the two? When to use one and when to use the other?

Answer (score 10):

`indicator_column` encodes the input to a `multi-hot` representation, not `one-hot` encoding.

The [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/indicator_column) clarifies more:

```
name = indicator_column(categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    'name', ['bob', 'george', 'wanda'])
columns = [name, ...]
features = tf.parse_example(..., features=make_parse_example_spec(columns))
dense_tensor = input_layer(features, columns)

dense_tensor == [[1, 0, 0]]  # If "name" bytes_list is ["bob"]
dense_tensor == [[1, 0, 1]]  # If "name" bytes_list is ["bob", "wanda"]
dense_tensor == [[2, 0, 0]]  # If "name" bytes_list is ["bob", "bob"]
```

The last two examples describe what is meant by `multi-hot` encoding. for example if the input be `["bob", "wanda"]` the encoding will be `[[1, 0, 1]]`.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the question in the comments above (by Ankit Seth), the docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/feature_columns#passing_feature_columns_to_estimators) say the following about deep models (as opposed to "wide", i.e. linear):

> `tf.estimator.DNNClassifier` and `tf.estimator.DNNRegressor`: Only accept
>   dense columns. Other column types must be wrapped in either an
>   `indicator_column` or `embedding_column`.

And if you try to pass a categorical column directly to a deep model, TF will throw the following error:

> ValueError: Items of feature_columns must be a _DenseColumn. You can
>   wrap a categorical column with an embedding_column or
>   indicator_column.

Answer (score 1):

You would use [categorical_column_with_*](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/embedding_column) to get a `_CategoricalColumn` to feed into a linear model; this column returns identity values, often using a vocabulary.

On the other hand, [indicator_column](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/indicator_column) is a multi-hot representation of a given categorical column and would be used if you want to feed the feature into a DNN, for example; it produces an `_IndicatorColumn`. [embedding_column](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/embedding_column) is analogous but you'd use it if your input is sparse.

Comment: So you are saying Categorical column can't be directly fed to DNN, unless wrapped by `indicator` or `embedded` column.

Comment: According to the docs the feature columns "should be instances of classes derived from FeatureColumn" 
-- embeddings will reduce the complexity of the data representation but I'm not sure that it's a requirement. 
 https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNClassifier