# What is the difference between a Categorical Column and a Dense Column?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, estimators

In Tensorflow, there are 9 different *feature columns*, arranged into three groups: *categorical*, *dense* and *hybrid*.

From reading the [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/feature_columns), I understand categorical columns are used to represent *discrete* input data with a numerical value. It gives the example of a categorical column called *categorical identity column*:

```
ID   Represented using one-hot encoding
0    [1, 0, 0, 0]
1    [0, 1, 0, 0]
2    [0, 0, 1, 0]
3    [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

But you also have a dense column called *indicator* column, which 'wraps'(?) a categorical column to produce something that looks almost identical:

```
Category (from category column)   Represented as...
0                                 [1, 0, 0, 0]
1                                 [0, 1, 0, 0]
2                                 [0, 0, 1, 0]
3                                 [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

So both 'categorical' and 'dense' columns seems to be able to represent discrete data, so that's not what distinguishes one from another.

My question is: ***In principle***, what are the difference between a 'categorical column' and a 'dense column'?

---

I have read [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/30343/56522) that explains the difference between indicator columns and categorical identity columns, but I am looking for a more generic answer distinguishing *categorical* and *dense* columns.

Answer (score 6):

## Sparse vs Dense

The '*categorical column*' is a **sparse** column. **Sparse** and **dense** columns (or matrices) are in a way opposites of each other.

**Sparse** columns usually contain a lot of zeros. Whereas, **dense** columns have more non-zero entries. This matters, because the way they are stored and processed can differ.

### Sparse

If we take your **sparse** example:

```
ID   Represented using one-hot encoding
0    [1, 0, 0, 0]
1    [0, 1, 0, 0]
2    [0, 0, 1, 0]
3    [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

What information needs to be stored to reconstruct this matrix? All you need is:

- The number of columns and rows
- Value for every non-zero entry

So, by having:

```
n_columns = 4
n_rows = 4
non_zero_entries = {
    (0, 0): 1,
    (1, 1): 1,
    (2, 2): 1,
    (3, 3): 1
}
```

you can reconstruct it. This means you don't need to store all the `16` integers to reconstruct the matrix.

In Tensorflow, the '*categorical column*' matrix, has the special property that it is a **one-hot encoding**, meaning that one and only one entry in the columns is non-zero. However, the **sparse** principle doesn't need to be **one-hot**.

For example:

```
matrix = [
    [0, 0,   0, 0],
    [0, 2,   0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0.5, 0] 
]
```

Can be reconstructed with:

```
n_columns = 4
n_rows = 3
non_zero_entries = {
    (1, 1): 2,
    (1, 3): 1,
    (2, 2): 0.5
}
```

Imagine a matrix of size $100 \times 100$. There are $10,000$ values in it. Now, suppose only $1$ entry is non-zero (for whatever reason). Then, this large $10,000$ values matrix, can be represented by:

```
n_columns = 100
n_rows = 100
non_zero_entries = {
    (x, y): 1
}
```

### Dense

One the other hand, **dense** columns are not stored by defining only the non-zero entries. The `0`s are also being stored.

While more memory intensive, they are less computationally expensive because they don't need to be reconstructed. Also, often the `0`s are likely to be changed over time, and if there is already an `int` being stored, no new memory locations need to be assigned.

## Usability

Not all algorithms can process a **sparse** matrix. Often, matrix operations require the whole vector be present. Depending on the implementation, the assumptions that non-present elements are zero is not there, therefore an explicit zero needs be stored and passed along.

Like you mentioned in your questions:

> But you also have a dense column called indicator column, which
>   'wraps'(?) a categorical column to produce something that looks almost
>   identical

This is true. What they represent can be exactly the same. However, how they are stored and the efficiency of the implementations differ.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. So I am now wondering why the Tensorflow team named it as Categorical vs Dense. I would have compared Categorical vs. Numerical, and Sparse vs. Dense. Any ideas?

Comment: The `categorical` column here is actually numerical (i.e. they are numbers). I would say a 'pure' categorical column would be for example `column = ['dog', 'cat', 'dog']`, which the *numerical one-hot* representation is `column = [[1,0],[0,1],[1,0]]`. So, in Tensorflow, both `categorical` and `dense` are numerical. Why `categorical` and not `sparse`? I think because `sparse` doesn't imply **one-hot**, but in most contex, categorical data is **one-hot** (i.e. each data point has one category).

Comment: btw, feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)